# Could the Japanese garrison at Rabaul have fed itself if it had been spread out over New Britain Island instead of being concentrated at Rabaul?

Tags: world-war-two, japan

Early in 1942, Japan seized the fine port at [Rabaul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabaul) on [New Britain Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Britain). They later concentrated around 100,000 men at Rabaul, many of whom starved after the Allies encircled and blockaded the base by capturing nearby territories. These Allied holdings included Port Gloucester and the western third of New Britain (and the Allies were able to interdict the intervening area).

Suppose the Japanese had spread out their forces more or less evenly on New Britain itself (and taken percentage casualties in line with their percentage losses of the island). Does New Britain, as opposed to Rabaul, have the resources to sustain a 100,000 Japanese force?

For reference, New Britain has about 14,000 square miles and is about the size of Taiwan, although it is much less fertile because it has mostly jungle. More to the point, New Britain today has a population of about 500,000 people, decidedly more than the occupation force, while Rabaul, at its (1990) peak had only 17,000 people, far less than the occupation force.

Comment: Well, they could have cleared the jungle, plowed the land, spread out and start farming :) No, at that time there was not enough food production for whole Japanese army. Unless you really beat swords into ploughs there was nothing meaningful Japanese could have done.

Comment: Since 90,000 Japanese were still alive to surrender in 1945 despite being cut-off for the last two years of the war, it seems that by and large they *were* able to sustain themselves using local resources. My guess would be that any actual starvation would have involved isolated detachments stationed far away from Rabaul, and that further dispersion would have increased rather than decreased starvation.

Comment: @rs.29 Well, it seems they did some farming :). [Self-sufficiency in Rabaul](http://ajrp.awm.gov.au/AJRP/remember.nsf/Web-Printer/353583121E7CA65ACA256A99001D9F0E?OpenDocument)

Comment: @ThirstforKnowledge Yes, I stand corrected :) Japanese troops in Rabaul were turning into farmers. In this link there are actually some pictures of them at work : http://ajrp.awm.gov.au/ajrp/ajrp2.nsf/WebI/Chapters/$file/Chapter7.pdf?OpenElement

Comment: related: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/60602/to-what-extent-is-the-flora-and-fauna-on-guadalcanal-edible/60616#60616

Comment: Urban pop of Japan < 40%. Finding an experienced farmer among soldiers must have been very easy. (anecdote from a friend)  My friend's  grandpa was recruited directly as Sargent because he was one of the few literate guys at his village.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demography_of_the_Empire_of_Japan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Japanese garrison could have fed itself because this is enough square miles to feed such a number of troops.

However, this does not change at all the issue of the war: New Britain offered no facilities for the development of ammunition nor military material, so the Japanese garrison in New Britain would have still been blockaded and bombed by the US until the capitulation in 1945.

Answer (score 1):

Umm, the Japanese garrison at Rabaul did feed itself, especially compared to other Japanese garrisons in the Pacific (Truk was not terrible, but in much worse shape than Rabaul.  Islands in the middle of the Pacific like Jaluit were in horrible shape.) As articles linked by others note, Japanese soldiers became highly proficient farmers and fishermen.  As the Australian general who accepted the Japanese surrender at Rabaul remarked, Rabaul achieved virtual self sufficiency "like a small independent country." Doubtful that many, if any, Japanese at Rabaul actually "starved, " while there are far better known cases elsewhere.